# How to nest a dictionary with a predefined key string python (2.x)?

Tags: python, dictionary

First of all, i'm sorry that i couldn't implement the available answers for this problem, i'm really new to python, i just have to build a json like this:

folder names = city names

```
{
    "Berlin": {
        "files":[ "file1.pdf", "file2.pdf"]
    },
    "Budapest": {
        "files":[ "file1.pdf", "file2.pdf"]
    }
}
```

I could done this almost with this

```
rootdir = "D:\\scripttest\\pdf"
content = {}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    content[root.split('\\')[-1]] = files
print content

with open("D:\\scripttest\\pdfconf.json", 'w') as pdfConf:
    json.dump(content, pdfConf)
```

This is my output:
`{"Berlin": ["file1.pdf", "file2.pdf"], "Budapest": ["file1.pdf", "file2.pdf"]}`

So I need to export my value as the the outer dict's value, and insert a new value in my dict, but i'm confused.
I would by happy for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly create the `dict` with `"files"` as a key.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    city = os.path.basename(root)
    content[city] = {'files': files}
```

Use the `os.path` module to manipulate paths rather than treating them as raw strings.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I see the logic from your code, and it did the trick of course.